# ImgBurn and adware, where is a safe place to download it?

Tags: iso-image, adware

ImgBurn has adware in it!

I just used it and now all my google results are redirecting to those ad like pages.

Where is a safe place to get it from?

I used betanews: http://fileforum.betanews.com/detail/ImgBurn/1128426215/1 (dont install from here!)

Comment: Was that the link recently posted as an answer to a previous question?

Answer (score 8):

I just used the betanews mirror and installed it for fun, there is no adware in it as far as I and my anti-malware programs can see. My google searches are not redirected in any browser - though of course that doesn't mean everything is fine, with computer software one can never really truly know ^^

Perhaps you clicked the fake download link of an advertisement on the site, instead of the imgburn download link?

Comment: +1: I almost clicked on the wrong button as well. It can be quite deceptive, I'll bet this is what happened.

Comment: +1: some ads seems to be designed to be mixed up with the real 'download' link

Comment: Same thing happened to me the first time I downloaded it.

Answer (score 4):

No it doesn't. I just binary compared the BetaNews one you linked to, to http://download.imgburn.com/SetupImgBurn_2.5.0.0.exe and they're identical.

I suspect your adware has come from somewhere else, or you clicked the wrong link.

By the way the official site is http://www.imgburn.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try their website. They have tons of mirrors.

[List of mirrors](http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download)

I've never used imgburn before, but I use [powerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/). I know it doesn't come with adware